# Set focus on a specific item of a combobox without selecting it

Tags: java, combobox, javafx-2, javafx, javafx-8

I am trying to make a ComboBox which has a functionality of search a match from its items.

Here is a code sample of what I have done,

```
ObservableList<String> ab = FXCollections.observableArrayList("z", "asxdf", "abasdf", "bcasdf", "b", "bc", "bcd", "c");

final ComboBox box = new ComboBox(ab);
box.setEditable(true);

box.setOnKeyReleased(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
   @Override
   public void handle(KeyEvent t) {

      box.show();

      for (String item : items) {
         if (item.startsWith(box.getEditor().getText())) {

             box.getSelectionModel().select(item); //which selects the item.

             break;
         }
      }
   }
});
```

Now the problem is `box.getSelectionModel().select(item);` selects that specific item which is typed in the ComboBox, but I don't want to select that item, I just want to hover on (focus on) that item like when mouse hovers.

Can anyone tell me the code to replace with `box.getSelectionModel().select(item);` and help me solve this problem.

Comment: Did you try getFocusModel().focus(int)? it is at least method of listView, which is the content of popup.

Comment: Kindly tell me how to get ListView of a ComboBox object.

Comment: you can use the lookup method of the Node class with the css-selector ".combo-box-popup .list-view"

Comment: @Sebastian, box.lookup(".combobox-box-popup"); is returning NULL.

Answer (score 6):

You can get the ListView from the ComboBox by this code:

```
ListView<?> lv = ((ComboBoxListViewSkin) getSkin()).getListView();
```

Then you can focus to the item:

```
lv.getFocusModel().focus(N);
```

or just scroll to it:

```
lv.scrollTo(N)
```

Comment: is this no longer a valid approach? i get "'getListView()' is not public in 'javafx.scene.control.skin.ComboBoxListViewSkin'. Cannot be accessed from outside package"

Answer (score 2):

to reply late, but I only faced that issue today after I migrated a hole application from Swing to FX. I am using Java 8. (still)

This is how I made it work. Hope it is will help in case someone still has this issue.

```java
public class MyComboBox extends ComboBox<String> {
    public EditorComboBox() {

        // this event is created when the internal listView is displayed
        setOnShowing(event -> {
            ComboBoxListViewSkin<?> skin = (ComboBoxListViewSkin<?>)getSkin();
            if (skin != null) {
                ((ListView<?>) skin.getPopupContent()).scrollTo(getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: no uncompileable snippets, please! Good approach, but needs cleanup ..